# cluster:node; need a way to differentiate in master when to fork worker

Tags: node.js, express

I use cluster and node.js. As per cluster documentation, I have master/worker setup and master forks workers on

```
 cluster.on("death", function() {
    cluster.fork()
 })
```

In worker in do some preprocessing before app.listen(3000). I think no point starting server if preprocess does not pass.

```
// In worker code
preProcess ( function(err) {
  if err
     exit()
  else
    app.listen(3000)

}}
```

Now my issue is the master clutser process keeps forking the workers and workers keep dying because the preprocess does not pass.

I need a way to differentiate in master when to fork worker.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) because you can inspect the variable code and signal to determine what wrong and when to fork.

```
  cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
    logger.log.warn('Worker server died (ID: %d, PID: %d)', worker.id, worker.process.pid);
    cluster.fork();
  });
```